# Can I upgrade my jetpack in Cortex Command?

Tags: cortex-command

I've been playing [Cortex Command](http://www.datarealms.com/games.php) after I got it this week in the Humble Indie Bundle and, for the most part, I think it's quite fun.

However, I'm noticing that when I order a new person/robot/zombie with lots of stuff (a heavy weapon, multiple weapons, etc) they don't go upwards when firing the jetpack. The jetpack is an important way to get around the terrain considering it can be destroyed and is a giant pain to walk around on. I think I'm interpreting an icon on the screen as "overburdened" when I fire the jetpack which explains why I can't take off, but the game is much more fun with use of the jetpack. Is there a way to upgrade it or get a more advanced version that can carry more load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the pyro.ini file in the cortexcommand directory. open it with notepad. about 3/4 of the way down the page, find the "heavy jetpack" line. change the max value to 50 and the min to 20. a few sections above that, there is another jetpack option. change the values in the same way.

Comment: On the Mac pyro.ini was in the app bundle (Show Package Contents...) then Contents > Resources > Base > Effects > Pyro, but that definitely did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

**Without editing the game files** as mentioned above, there's no way to upgrade your jetpack.  That said, different bodies have different jetpacks, and different weights.  For example, some of the bodies have very short-burning jetpacks, and some of them can burn for much longer.  Some bodies have jetpacks which can lift more than others, as well.  Experiment with different bodies to see which ones you like the best.  As a general rule, lighter characters will have more lift than heavier characters from the get-go, but may not be able to carry as much as them.

Additionally, the best way I've found to get some extra height in a tight spot, is to crouch, and then stand up quickly (walk in either direction) and activate your jetpack.  The added thrust from your legs will give you some good momentum into the air, if you're loaded down with gear.

**EDIT:**
Oh, I forgot to mention the single most helpful thing I have to give.  If your body is carrying a digging tool (not a shovel, though), you can use it to boost yourself mid-flight.  If you fire it downwards while activating your jetpack, your thrust will increase *substantially*.  Always make sure your heavy bodies are carrying diggers.

Answer (score -2):

You need to look up using the mouse.

Comment: I'm not convinced this actually makes you go upwards any faster.